# стандарты GNU C++ и GNU C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Почему `gcc` компилирует этот код для стандарта `GNU C++`, но не компилирует для `GNU C++11`?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char *s = "string";
    std::cout << s[[]{ return 1; }()];
}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка компиляции?

Comment: @pavel `expected primary expression before ')' token`

Comment: Как вы компилируете в режиме gnu++? @pavel, у меня так: http://pastebin.com/qYVWNqNu

Comment: @PinkTux в настройках компилятора есть выбор

Comment: А где у `g++` находятся настройки? Ключи командной строки - знаю, настроек что-то не припомню.

Comment: Кстати  gcc в вопросе это опечатка? g++ имелся в виду?

Comment: VC++ ругается насчет атрибутов... Это не расширения какие-то GCC? Потому как исправить на [0,[..далее по тексту)] - и все работает :) Похоже, конструкция `[[` сбивает с толку. В GCC такого расширения нет?

Comment: @pavel @PinkTux В настройках среды `DevC++ 5.11` иду в `tools\compiler options\code generation`, там есть выбор между стандартами `ISO C++, ISO C++11, GNU C++, GNU C++11` и некоторыми другими. А сверху ещё написано `compiler set - TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release`. Я компилирую не из командной строки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что это запрещено [стандартом](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.grammar#7) C++14(по ссылке более новая версия черновика):

> **[dcl.attr.grammar]p6** Two consecutive left square bracket tokens shall
>   appear only when introducing an attribute-specifier. [ Note: If two
>   consecutive left square brackets appear where an attribute-specifier
>   is not allowed, the program is ill-formed even if the brackets match
>   an alternative grammar production. — end note ]

Там даже пример есть:

```
y[[] { return 2; }()] = 2; // error even though attributes are not allowed
// in this context.
```

Ну и первая строка у Вас тоже не очень, должно быть так:

```
const char *s = "string";
```

Comment: Стандартом каким? А в `GNU C++` почему компилируется?

Comment: А чуть подробнее про эти атрибуты не поделитесь - простым языком :)?

Comment: @IGORb, Стандартом C++14. Полагаю, что в 11 версии этот запрет был уже, т.к. аттрибуты появились в 11 версии.

Comment: @Harry, а там пока нечем делиться. Есть пара вспомогательных аттрибутов, которые помогают помечать разные части программы для компилятора. Как например `[[noreturn]]`, говорит, что функция никогда не выполняет `return`: это может помочь компилятору с оптимизацией, атрибут deprecated, для пометки устаревших функций и прочего. На подходе атрибуты, чтобы помечать переменные, которые не используются сознательно и fallthrough для case'ов в select. Пока это всё просто проба пера и далеко не то, что есть в C#, где атрибуты помогают много интересных штук делать.

Comment: @IGORb, не полностью ответил на Ваш вопрос: если где-то этот код компилируется. то это ошибка этого компилятора. Ни при каких условиях он не должен компилироваться.

Comment: @ixSci но вы же сами сказали, что атрибуты появились только с 11 версии, получается до 11 такой ошибки не должно возникнать... почему тогда он не должен компилироваться?

Comment: @IGORb, до 11 версии не было и лямбд, а у Вас в коде она есть. Поэтому, если компилирует одно согласно правилам 11 версии, то и другое должно компилировать так же.

Comment: @ixSci а как может помочь компилятору знание что функция не делает return? Он сам это не видит что ли?

Comment: @pavel, если у Вас код в библиотеке, то может и не видеть. Можете почитать изначальное [предложение](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1453.htm), там должно быть описано, что, как и почему.

Comment: Кстати, а как более корректно обходить такие ситуации? Пока на ум пришло два варианта:  std::cout << s[([]{ return 1; }())]; или std::cout << s[0|[]{ return 1; }()]; Ваши варианты/предложения?

Comment: @Majestio, мой вариант прост: так не надо писать, в этом нет никакой необходимости.

Comment: @ixSci, необходимость - вопрос спорный. Допустим, правите чужой код. Хочешь-не-хочешь, а править нужно.

Comment: @Majestio, этого не может быть в чужом коде, потому что не может быть скомпилировано.

Comment: @ixSci, почему же не может? Вон ТС явно пишет, что компиляторами (с разными стандартами) может быть скомпилированно, а может быть и нет.

Comment: @Majestio, это бесполезный разговор. Я, кажется, вполне ясно выразил свою позицию.